# css javascript php div show/hide

Tags: php, javascript, css, html

this is the code i have:

```
<?
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($result1)) {
       echo '<a href="#" onclick="showhide("'.$row1->id.'");">Name</a>';
       while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
          echo '<div id="'.$row1->id.'">';
          echo 'blabla';
          echo '</div>';
       }
    }
?>
    <script> 
    var state = 'none';
    function showhide(layer_ref){
    if(state == 'block'){
    state = 'none';
    }else{
    state = 'block';
    }
    if(document.all){ //IS IE 4 or 5 (or 6 beta)
    eval("document.all." +layer_ref+ ".style.display = state");
    }
    if (document.layers) { //IS NETSCAPE 4 or below
    document.layers[layer_ref].display = state;
    }
    if (document.getElementById &&!document.all) {
    hza = document.getElementById(layer_ref);
    hza.style.display = state;
    }
    }
    </script>
```

this outputs something like:

```
Name
  blabla
Name
  blabla
...
```

and when clicking on the head (name) it should toggle it contents (show/hide)
but it doesn't. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: **Do not** use `eval()`, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(id) {
        var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
            if (state == 'block') {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
</script>
```

[Live demo here>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kefpTo)

Comment: mmh, when inspecting the elements, `onclick="toggle("'.$row1->project_id.'");"` outputs: `onclick="toggle( "18");"` (include strange space before 18), it only displays the heads (Name, Name, ..) with a big lot of whitespace between them...